# What was the reason to change the character names in the English version of Xenoblade Chronicles compared with the Japanese version?

Tags: translation, xenoblade-chronicles

As can be seen from the track listing of the [original soundtrack](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Xenoblade_Original_Soundtrack#Songs) (just serving as a nice overview) a lot of names are different in the Japanese and English version. For example, Aegir/Egil, Xanthe/Zanza, Fiorung/Fiora but also [Shuruku/Shulk](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Shulk) <sup>(massive spoilers)</sup>. While I still get it with Fiorung (which doesn't sound like a female name, while Fiora does) the other examples are less apparent — e.g., why Zanza, not Xanthe?

Is there a documented reason behind this decision?

Comment: Is the game dubbed in english?  If so, then the change of names might have to match the mouth animation.  An A might mouth out to an E, X to Z, etc ..

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer: That'd be a possibility, yes. But the [dub](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUnQQxPlaWo&list=PL6AD766CA7390A7A4) isn't that great, anyway. Also, the cutscenes are not pre-rendered and I'm pretty sure they could have changed them if lip synch would have been an issue (the engine seems quite flexible).

Comment: It's not translation, it's transliteration: they bring a word into the next language according to the next language's grammar and its closest equivalent sounds. In a historical example: Greek has no 'sh' sound, and male names typically end with an 's', so the Aramaic name 'Yeshua' was transliterated in Greek as 'Iesous'. It's an accommodation for how the next language works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of those actually look like the same name with me, but written in Japanese. This is a common phenomenon with media translated between the two.

For example, lets look at the name "Shulk". Well, we want Japanese players to have a decent time pronouncing the name so lets make sure they can.

Oh dear. our voice actor can't pronounce the letter L, because in japanese the english letters R and L are covered by the same letter. This means his name sounds like "Shurk".
But there is another problem. Japanese doesn't have a "urk" syllable. To get around this, they add a small vowel sound between the letters to turn it into "uruk". Finally, japanese ends words with a vowel sound, so the last 'u' gets added in, giving you Shuruku.

The same process occurs in reverse

That means the names are in fact the same, they are just the Japanese pronounciations of the same names. The same rules pretty much apply for the other names, they are adjusted to make them natural to pronounce in each language.

Generally you shouldn't identify these as being "different names" but rather being different  ways of spelling the same name because that name is pronounced differently. I would say they are both meant to represent the same name, and one has just been "translated" just like any other word.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. This is a Japanese game, and initially made in Japanese. So, the name would have been "Shuruk" (however that is pronounced) initially and then changed to "Shulk" afterwards. While I get your English->Japanese explanation, the process would have to take place in the other direction. This is probably obvious to you, but since I have no clue whatsoever about Japanese, I still not sure I really get your argument, sorry. Are you saying both versions of the name are transliterations of what would be pronounced equally?

Comment: @bitmask
Both of the names are supposed to represent the same thing. They are just modified one way or another for ease of pronunciation. In the real world, the name John in english is Jan, or Juan, or Juan in other languages. Normally we don't translate those, we just leave them as is. However, when translating between Japanese and English it is more common to actually translate the names. 
Both versions of the name are transliterations of people trying to pronounce the same name.

Comment: @bitmask Shulk may actually sound the most accurate to a japanese speaker, because the sounds in Shuruku don't exist in english.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, rather than just plain transliteration or translation, sometimes the localization team opts for a name which sounds better (or makes a more obvious correlation) when spoken in English. Take Karuna/Sharla for example: her name would sound too much like "Karma" if it was left as close to Japanese as possible. At any rate, the "altering" of names is a kind of constant when localizing Japanese games; such as Elza being renamed Zael in The Last Story, Ende and Ceres being renamed Aeron and Elena in Pandora's Tower, or even Azure renamed Inigo and Aqua renamed Azura in the most recent Fire Emblem games (Awakening and Fates, respectively). Truth is, there seems to be no pattern to the translation/transliteration/adaptation of names from Japanese to English, but the names' context is maintained when a simple adaptation/translation isn't possible or desirable. One can only guess, however, at specific reasons why names are translated the way they are (save for Ice Climbers "Popo", which was renamed "Pepe" in Germany because of his original name's meaning in German).